# How to use the OnClick attribute in XML for a button inside a ListView item?

Tags: android

I have a listView that uses a customAdapter and a has a custom layout. the listView Item contains an Image, Text and Button. I added an onClick attribute in the Xml `android:onClick="onClicked"`. Then I made the method to respond to the Button

```
public void onClicked(View view){
 ......
}
```

but I don't know how to make it make a different code depending on the button position in the listView, if you know how to solve this problem please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, in your case you have to programatically set the `onClickListener` on your adapter code

Comment: can't I use a switch or something

Comment: no you can only use `android:onClick` on an XML that is going to be used by an Activity, nowhere else will it work (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter for your listview. You can program your button for click within that custom adapter ..